# Tomar fecha actual automaticamente

Tags: php, mysql

Buen día

Ocupo ayuda y orientación estoy realizando una consulta en la cual mediante un php al correrlo me genera en automático un archivo EXCEL de todo lo registrado en el día pero como somos 2 turnos ocupo que el php se separe por turno, tengo las siguientes 2 consultas y me funcionan pero como puedo hacer que la fecha la detecte según el día en que estamos sin necesidad que lo cambie manual.

1er turno

```
SELECT 
      id_re,
      cantidad_material_re, 
      peso_material_re, 
      serie_material_re, 
      numero_etiqueta_re, 
      total_etiquetas, 
      fecha_registro_re 
FROM registro_preconteo 
WHERE fecha_registro_re BETWEEN '2022-07-15 00:00:00' AND '2022-07-15 15:30:00' ORDER BY fecha_registro_re ASC;
```

2do turno

```
SELECT 
      id_re, 
      cantidad_material_re, 
      peso_material_re, 
      serie_material_re, 
      numero_etiqueta_re, 
      total_etiquetas, 
      fecha_registro_re 
FROM registro_preconteo WHERE fecha_registro_re BETWEEN '2022-07-14 15:30:00' AND '2022-07-14 23:59:59' 
ORDER BY fecha_registro_re ASC;
```

Otra ya lo probe con la funcion NOW() y tambien me genera el reporte pero de todo el dia y no por horario como los 2 de arriba alguna idea de como solucionarlo les dejo la consulta con NOW() no se con cual de las 2 formas sea mas sencillo

```
SELECT 
      id_re, 
      cantidad_material_re, 
      peso_material_re, 
      serie_material_re, 
      numero_etiqueta_re, 
      total_etiquetas, 
      fecha_registro_re 
FROM registro_preconteo 
WHERE CAST(fecha_registro_re AS DATE) = DATE(NOW()) 
ORDER BY fecha_registro_re ASC;
```

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de dato es `fecha_registro_re`?

Comment: Es datetime pero si busco asi como estan las consultas si me arroja resultados

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT 
      id_re, 
      cantidad_material_re, 
      peso_material_re, 
      serie_material_re, 
      numero_etiqueta_re, 
      total_etiquetas, 
      fecha_registro_re 
FROM registro_preconteo WHERE fecha_registro_re BETWEEN 
CURDATE() + '15:30:00' AND CURDATE() + '23:59:59'
```

Un saludo!

Comment: Hola sabes que ya corri tu consulta me genera el archivo excel sin datos 
Lo corri manual en la terminal de comandos y me arroja la siguiente alerta
"Empty set, 6 warnings (0.01 sec)"